# VS Code debug console won't work with Python input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-python

I have some simple code that works fine everywhere except the Debug Console on VS Code.

Here it is:

```
pounds = int(input("How much do you weigh in pounds? "))
kilos = pounds * 0.45359237
print("You weight " + str(kilos) + " kilograms.")
```

If you use the `launch.json` configuration of `"console": "internalConsole",`, then the output will go to the debug console, which doesn't work. If you do `"console": "integratedTerminal"`, the output will work and it will go to the terminal, but, it will make a new debug console each time, and eventually it will stop working on the 33 time. I have the screenshot below. The error is not shown in the terminal, but in a pop-up. The error states:

> The terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" terminated with exit code: 256.

So there are two problems:

1. Debug console won't work with `input()`
2. Terminal makes too many debug consoles, causing it to error.

I am confused as to how anyone uses python on VS code, because I can't even get it to work. I guess I can delete the consoles each time it reaches 33, but that seems inefficient and not how VS Code was intended to be used.

screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. According to the information you provided, when I use `"console": "integratedTerminal"` in VSCode, the results will be executed sequentially in the same terminal:

   [image]
2. When using `"internalConsole"`, the result will not be executed normally, because currently the debugging console in VSCode is only used to display output.
3. In addition, we can also use `"console": "externalTerminal"`, which can also accept input:

   [image]

Reference: [console in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).